# Run texi2pdf without calling bibtex

Tags: r, sweave

When I run `texi2pdf` (or `texi2dvi`) I get the error below. Is it possible to have the `texi2dvi` function execute LaTeX without bibtex?

```
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'FactBook-Supplement.Rnw' failed.
BibTeX errors:
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file O:\Institutional Research\IR metrics\Fact Book\Supplement\build\2012-Winter.0\FactBook-Supplement.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file O:\Institutional Research\IR metrics\Fact Book\Supplement\build\2012-Winter.0\FactBook-Supplement.aux
```

Comment: Why not fix your bibtex problems instead? You probably need to remove the `.aux` files first, or there might be something wrong in your tex document (e.g. did you set the bib style?).

Comment: I am not using bibtex, or any bibliography. It seems that the texi2dvi is calling bibtex even though there is not bibliography information in my tex file. The reason I think the problem is with R's use of LaTeX is that the document works fine outside of R.

Comment: I do not think R calls bibtex if there is no bib. Does it work if you remove the two `.aux` files?